# how to load using webpack import in sub-directories?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm using `webpack` to do **`dynamic import`** for loading files in sub-directories:

```
const requireApplicationRoutes = require.context('./', true, /routes.js$/);

let routes: any = [];

requireApplicationRoutes.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  routes = routes.concat(requireApplicationRoutes(fileName).default);
});
```

How to do that (`import`) with `typescript` in `esnext` module? (this code in typescript file) like `import('./**/*.ts')`?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with ES dynamic import: it only lets you import a specific module name, not list a directory of modules.  However, you can probably still use `require.context` in an esnext module if you are processing the module with webpack.

Comment: well, the problem is the code-splitting doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `webpack`, `typescript` and `esnext`, you can loading files in sub directories using `require.context`, just use [lazy option from webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/9560af5545e4f89f330d32f5158ddbe4bf0003c4/lib/ContextModule.js#L14).

Your `typescript` code should look like:

```
const requireApplicationRoutes = (require.context as any)('./', true, /routes.ts$/, 'lazy');

requireApplicationRoutes.keys().forEach((fileName: any) => {
  routes = routes.concat(requireApplicationRoutes(fileName).default);
});
```

**But**, `require.context` return `Promise` in `webpack` version, so your code should be:

```
const routes = Promise.all(
  requireApplicationRoutes.keys().map((fileName: string) => requireApplicationRoutes(fileName).then((route: any) => route.default)),
).then(([ modules ]) => modules);
```

And you should have all the lazy bundles in your files and routes are array of your routes. :)

Comment: Works! Thank you!!